# Register multiple routes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I want to register multiple routes for mvc and my required Urls are as below:

```
http://mysite.com/myapps/[action]/[id]
http://mysite.com/myapps/[parameter]/build/
http://mysite.com/myapps/[parameter]/build/MyType1/[action]/[id]
http://mysite.com/myapps/[parameter]/build/MyType2/[action]/[id]
http://mysite.com/myapps/[parameter]/build/MyType3/[action]/[id]
http://mysite.com/myapps/[parameter]/build/MyType4/[action]/[id]
http://mysite.com/myapps/[parameter]/build/MyTyp51/[action]/[id]
http://mysite.com/myapps/[parameter]/messages/[action]/[id]
http://mysite.com/myapps/[parameter]/users/[action]/[id]
http://mysite.com/account/[action]/[id]
http://mysite.com/help/[action]/[id]
http://mysite.com/videos/[action]/[id]
```

how i can acheive?

thanks

Comment: Have you consulted: [this](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=814)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the [MapRoute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470521%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method defined in the [RouteCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.routing.routecollection%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) (Route) class.

If you open up the **RouteConfig.cs** file (found under the `App_Start` folder), you will see the `RegisterRoutes()` method. Within this method, you will see the default route that looks something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

To add your custom routes you will add something like this:

```
// Make sure your custom routes are placed BEFORE the default route
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "MyRoute01",
    url: "myapps/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "myapps", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional}
);

routes.MapRoute(
   name: "MyRoute02",
   url: "myapps/{parameter}/build/{MyType}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "myapps", action = "Index", parameter = "MyDefaultParamValue", MyType="MyType1", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

The routes above is nothing more than a response to "how you can achieve" registering multiple routes. In other words, the example above is nothing more than a tip to get you started.

We won't be able to assist you in the exact routes since you didn't give us the specifics of the names of your Controllers and Actions nor did you specify the meaning of your URL patterns - i.e. what classes and methods (controllers and actions) do you want the custom routes to resolve to?

Keep in mind that an URL will eventually call exactly one method (Action) that lives in a specific class (Controller). So, in your custom routes, you can create any URL pattern that you wish, but you must understand that the route must specify a Controller and an Action that you want to fire off based on the URL pattern.

If the above information is news to you, it would be wise for you to read up on how the MVC Routing System works (and doesn't work, for that matter).